# Identifying old files types

Tags: database, file-extension

I have three files with these extensions ".mrf, .md5, .ptr" that were created in 2009, 2007 and apprx. 2012 respectively.

I know that file types could be different than the extension. For example, md5 is a hashing algorithm but in this case it is an extension for large files (between 1 and 200MB).

The files were taken from discontinued book software which makes me think that these are database files but not sure which type.

This is what I have tried so far:

- Using [TrID](https://mark0.net/soft-tridnet-e.html). Results: null.
- Using Linux `file` command. Result: "data".
- [CheckFileType](http://checkfiletype.com/) website. Results: `application/octet-stream`
- Tried to open the files using an MDB viewer and DBF viewer with no luck.
- Opened the files in text editors and HEX editors to check for the first few characters and there were unreadable.

Are there any ways I could figure out the file types?

Comment: Maybe this helps? https://filext.com/file-extension/MRF

Comment: Thanks for the link. I checked that website. The most related option is "MeterReading (Data) by Dataconomy". The issue is the website is discontinued and there no available downloads of that software anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

#### Are there any ways I could figure out the file types?

Not without testing a file with software that has used that file type. In many cases there are multiple programs using a particular file extension.

Examples follow.

**.mrf file extension**

Used by:

- [Mouse Recorder Freeware for Windows](https://www.mouserecorder.com/index.html)
- GPS Pathfinder Office by Trinble Navigation Limited
- Grade Busters Teacher Tools File
- Macintosh Font
- Marks Russel File
- MeterReading (Data) by Dataconomy
- Morpheus (Saved Game)
- MultiEx Commander (Resource File) by XeNTaX
- WinMorph Project Information File

Sources [MRF File Extension - What is an .mrf file and how do I open it?](https://fileinfo.com/extension/mrf) and [MRF File Extension - What is it? How to open an MRF file?](https://filext.com/file-extension/MRF)

**.ptr file extension**

Used by:

- OS/2 (cursor image)
- QMail Qwk Reader Pointer
- CX-Protocol
- Media Player Classic
- PhotoPhilia
- Public Talks Application
- Trendyflash Site Builder

Sources [PTR File Extension - What is it? How to open a PTR file?](https://filext.com/file-extension/PTR) and [PTR File - What is it and how do I open it?](https://file.org/extension/ptr)